# Chromecast from a node media server

Tags: node.js, http-live-streaming, chromecast

I used npm [hls-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls-server) to setup an hls streaming server on my dev machine. Then i took android sample app and tried adding another video with url that of my localhost. 
The video plays fine inside the sample app but i am unable to cast it to chromecast.
I tried changing mediatype and also setup cors proxy using npm package [cors-anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere).

I used [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg) to generate hls playlist and .ts files. 
Would be great if someone can help out.

Comment: I would play other sample HLS stream with Android Sample App, to make sure that Android sample app doesn't have any problem to cast HLS streams. If the sample stream plays fine. Then, I would check for the receiver logs to see whether the problem is in stream format or receiver. Feel free to share the logs or failure stream to get additional help.

Comment: I figured out, it was problem with my HLS steram. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my HLS stream. What I did was to use sample receiver app from google and attached debugger to see error code/exceptions.
Then i took another video and used ffmpeg to produce hls again which worked out quite fine.